# CSS Semi-Transparent box

Tags: html, css, web

I want a semi transparent div for better readability of the site's content, over my background image. The div has rounded corners, and I am having trouble combining that with transparency

How can I do this with CSS?

Comment: Which box do you want to be semi-transparent? The one with the background image with rounded corners? Well - make the image semi-transparent!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just update your css and fixes you errors :

```
.TextBOx{
  -moz-border-radius:30px;
  -webkit-border-radius:30px;
  border-radius:30px;
  border: #solid 10px #000;
  background-color: rgba(105,100,100,0.8);
  width:80%;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
```

Goed so ?

Answer (score 3):

Cross-browser opacity:

```
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=75)"; /* IE8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* Old IE */
-khtml-opacity: 0.75; /* Old Safari */
-moz-opacity: 0.75; /* Old Firefox, Netscape */
opacity: 0.75; /* Standard */
```

A tool to build it for you:
https://www.alphachannelgroup.com/resources/tools/css-cross-browser-opacity-tool/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `opacity:0.5;` to make the object half transparent. Form 0 to 1 (100%). But that will make the children transparent also. So you may Better use a transparent background-Color. Like this: `background-Color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);` for a half transparent white Background.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this CSS code for making transparent.

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1; /*to fix the has layout bug in IE older version*/
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here is the Demo link http://jsbin.com/kibiruva/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use `opacity` or `rgba()` to define your background color.

Opacity x-browser example:

```
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=50)"; /* IE8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* Old IE */
-khtml-opacity: 0.50; /* Old Safari */
-moz-opacity: 0.50; /* Old Firefox, Netscape */
opacity: 0.50; /* Standard */
```

RGBA Example:

```
background-Color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
*filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF); /*Old IE*/
```